# Evolution of a charge density field with a continuity equation

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, charge

Imagine you have a field, $\rho(\mathbf x, t)$, that represents the density of electric charge in a region of space.

It is well known that
(If $\nabla \cdot \mathbf u = 0$):
$$
\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} + \mathbf u \cdot \nabla \rho = 0
$$
This is the continnuity equation, which tells that the  quantity $Q$ such that:
$$
Q = \int_V d^3 \mathbf x \; \rho(\mathbf x, t)
$$
is conserved.

Now, in the electrostatic case, $\mathbf F = \int \rho \mathbf E \; dV$, where $\mathbf E = -\nabla \phi$

My question is: can we determine an equation of motion for $\rho(\mathbf x, t)$ purely on terms of itself? Let me explain:

We have that:
$$
\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} + \mathbf u \cdot \nabla \rho = 0
$$
and (by Newton's Laws)
$$
\frac{d \mathbf p}{dt} = \frac{d ( m \mathbf u)}{dt}  = \mathbf F = \int_V d^3 \mathbf x \; \rho \mathbf E
$$
where $m$ is the mass of the field. Using the identity $\mathbf E = -\nabla \phi$:
$$
m\frac{d \mathbf u}{dt} = -\int_V d^3 \mathbf x \; \rho \nabla \phi
$$
Finally, knowing that: $\nabla^2 \phi = -\rho / \varepsilon_0$, we have three equations that determine the movement of the field $\rho(\mathbf x, t)$:
$$
\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} + \mathbf u \cdot \nabla \rho = 0
$$

$$
m\frac{d \mathbf u}{dt} = -\int_V d^3 \mathbf x \; \rho \nabla \phi
$$

$$
\nabla^2 \phi = -\frac{\rho}{\varepsilon_0}
$$
What I mean exactly with "purely on terms of the density"? As you see, the two variables $\mathbf u$ and $\phi$, could be determined from $\rho$. But at first glance, it seems impossible to substitute this three equations into one purely in terms of $\rho(\mathbf x, t)$. Is this even possible? Does this system requires from numerical simulations? Is there a better way to analize this system and find its equations?

Comment: Are you looking for the [Vlasov-Poisson equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vlasov_equation#The_Vlasov-Poisson_equation)?